# dockerfile build error to copy in parent folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My project structure :

```
- docker-compose.yml
- api
 |- composer.json
- php
 |- Dockerfile
```

My Dockerfile in php folder :

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ git libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony_docker

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
RUN mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
RUN git config --global user.email "you@example.com" \ 
    && git config --global user.name "Your Name"


COPY ../api/composer.json .

COPY ../api/. .

RUN composer install
```

My docker-compose :

```
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./php
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
```

I got a error when i start my docker-compose (docker-compose up -d --build)

> => ERROR [ 8/10] COPY ../api/composer.json .                                                                                      0.0s

> => ERROR [ 9/10] COPY ../api/. .

I cannot copy my composer.json file locally to my container to then install the dependencies

Comment: You can't copy files from outside the build context.

Comment: In your compose file below `build:`  => `context: .` (that's the default so you can omit) and `dockerfile: php/Dockerfile`. Then in your Dockerfile => `COPY api/composer.json .` As reported above by Hans, and clearly stated in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy): `The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.`